# where is bcc in electron cache

Tags: electrum

has electron cache 2 history pages: bitcoins and bcc?
in a youtube video I see only one history page with a sending and receiving tab: what is this:bitcoins or bcc?
I want to start a wallet with 0 bitcoins and 1 bcc via a seed of an old blockchain.info wallet.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your BCC balance won't be shown in Electrum, Electrum shows **only** the BTC balance.

But there's a changed version of Electrum that supports BCC, [**Electron Cash**](http://www.electroncash.org) (NOT *Electrum Cash*), and that one doesn't show the BTC balance.

Guess which one is Electron Cash, which one is Electrum!

[image]
[image]

Here are their icons, the one on the left is Electrum, the other one is Electron Cash

[image]